# Can Fock space be written as a tensor product? (Cohen Tannoudji Vol. 3 book)

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space

$\newcommand{\ket}[1]{\left|#1\right\rangle}
\newcommand{\tl}[1]{\tag{#1}\label{#1}}$

Let us define the Fock space for bosons (S) by:
$$
\mathcal{E}_{Fock}^{S}=\mathcal{E}_{Fock}^{S}(0) \oplus\mathcal{E}_{Fock}^{S}(1) \oplus\mathcal{E}_{Fock}^{S}(2)\oplus \dots \oplus\mathcal{E}^S_{Fock}(N) \oplus \dots
$$
where $\mathcal{E}_{Fock}^{S}(N)$ is state space of $N$ particles after symetrization.

The questions below come from reading the  Comments from Vol. 3 from Choen Tannoudji book p. 1595 and 1596.

Is it true or false that

> $\mathcal{E}_{Fock}^{S}$ can be written as the tensor product of Fock spaces $\mathcal{E}_{Fock}^{u_i}$ associated with the individual orthogonal states $\ket{u_i}$, each $\mathcal{E}_{Fock}^{u_i}$ being spanned by the kets $\ket{n_i}$ where $n_i$ takes on all integer values (from zero to infinity for bosons, from zero to one for fermions)

($n_i$ is the occupation number)

In other words, is the following equality true?
$$
\mathcal{E}_{Fock}^{S} = \mathcal{E}_{Fock}^{u_1}\otimes \mathcal{E}_{Fock}^{u_2}\otimes\dots\otimes\mathcal{E}_{Fock}^{u_i}\otimes\dots\tl{01}
$$

The justification provided in the book is that:
The basis states of $\mathcal{E}_{Fock}^{S}$ which I know can be written as
$$
\!\!\!\!\!\!\ket{n_i,n_j,\dots,n_l,\dots} =cS_N \ket{1:u_i;2:u_i;..;n_i:u_i;n_i+1:u_j;..;n_i+n_j:u_j;\dots} \tl{02}
$$
(with $S_N$ being the symmetrization operator $S_N=1/N!\sum_\alpha P_\alpha$ and $c$ a normalization constant which is derived in p. 1594, and which I think it is irrelevant)

can also according to the comment of the book be written as the following tensor product:

$$
\ket{n_1,n_2,\dots,n_i,\dots}=\ket{n_1}\otimes \ket{n_2}\otimes\dots\otimes\ket{n_i}\otimes\dots \tl{03}
$$

I cannot justify and here is a simple example that allow us to compare \eqref{02} and \eqref{03}, from \eqref{02} we have:
$$
\ket{n_1=2,n_3=1}=c\frac{1}{3!}\sum_{\alpha} P_\alpha \ket{1:u_1;2:u_1;3:u_3}
$$
the $\ket{1:u_1;2:u_1;3:u_3}$ is what Tannoudji calls the mathematical ket:
$$
\ket{1:u_1;2:u_1;3:u_3}=\ket{1:u_1}\otimes\ket{2:u_1}\otimes\ket{3:u_3}
$$
Explicitly the previous summation yields:
$$
\ket{n_1=2,n_3=1}=c\frac{2}{3!}(\ket{1:u_1;2:u_1;3:u_3}+\ket{1:u_1;2:u_3;3:u_1}+\ket{1:u_3;2:u_1;3:u_1})
$$
On the other hand \eqref{03} tells us that:
$$
\ket{n_1=2,n_3=1}=\ket{n_1=2}\otimes \ket{n_3=1}
$$
and since
$$
\ket{n_1=2} = \frac{1}{2!}\sum_\alpha P_\alpha\ket{1:u_1;2:u_1}=\ket{1:u_1;2:u_1}
$$
and
$$
\ket{n_3=1} = \frac{1}{1!}\sum_\alpha P_\alpha\ket{3:u_3}=\ket{3:u_3}
$$
we find that
$$
\ket{n_1=2,n_3=1}=\ket{1:u_1;2:u_1}\otimes \ket{3:u_3} = \ket{1:u_1;2:u_1;3:u_3}
$$
Clearly \eqref{02} and \eqref{03} are different.

**Questions:** Where is the mistake and how to make compatible the direct sum point of view on the Fock space and the tensor product point of view?
I also would appreciate some other sources that I can read about this subject, so far only in this one I found this tensor product view.

Thank you

Comment: The red coloring is telling you that MathJax doesn’t support \ket. You can use | and \rangle to make a ket.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, $(2)$ and $(3)$ are *formally* different kets. The Hilbert spaces $\mathcal E_{Fock}^S$ and $\mathcal E_{Fock}^{u_1} \otimes \mathcal E_{Fock}^{u_2} \otimes \ldots$ are not *equal*. They are canonically isomorphic, however, so for all intent and purposes, they can be identified.

The reason for this is that they both have an orthonormal basis of kets $|n_1,n_2,\ldots\rangle$ indexed by lists of integers (with finitely many non-zero terms). So there is a natural unitary operator :
$$U\left\{\begin{array}{ccc}\mathcal E_{Fock}^{u_1} \otimes \mathcal E_{Fock}^{u_2} \otimes \ldots & \longrightarrow & \mathcal E_{Fock}^S \\
|n_1\rangle\otimes |n_2\rangle\otimes \ldots& \longmapsto & cS_N |1:u_i;2:u_i;..;n_i:u_i;n_i+1:u_j;..;n_i+n_j:u_j;\dots\rangle\end{array}\right.$$

You don't lose much by using $U$ to identify both Hilbert spaces and write :
$$|n_1\rangle\otimes |n_2\rangle\otimes \ldots= cS_N |1:u_i;2:u_i;..;n_i:u_i;n_i+1:u_j;..;n_i+n_j:u_j;\dots\rangle$$