# Partition function for independent particles

Tags: quantum-mechanics, statistical-mechanics, condensed-matter, many-body, partition-function

I am trying to understand Section 3.8.3, "Independent particles", of Piers Coleman's Introduction to Many-Body Physics (self-study, mathematics background). He considers "a system of independent particles with many energy levels $E_\lambda$," with Hamiltonian
$$H - \mu N = \sum_{\lambda} (E_\lambda - \mu) \hat{n}_\lambda.$$
He then writes

> the partition function is given by a product of the individual partition functions:
> $$Z = \text{Tr} \left[\prod_{\lambda \, \otimes} e^{-\beta (E_\lambda - \mu) \hat{n}_\lambda} \right].$$
> Since the trace of an (exterior) product of matrices, this is equal to the product of their individual traces ($\text{Tr} \prod_{\lambda \otimes} = \prod_\lambda \text{Tr}$),
> $$Z = \prod_\lambda \text{Tr} [e^{-\beta (E_\lambda - \mu)\hat{n}_\lambda}] = \prod_{\lambda} Z_\lambda.$$

I am not sure how to understand this abstract presentation (for example, I do not know what should be understood by an "exterior product of matrices", or the use of the $\otimes$ symbol), and when I attempt a concrete example to gain more intuition, I am unable to reproduce the result.

For example, I can consider a two-level system containing three particles, so that the three-particle eigenstates of $H$ are $|30\rangle$, $|21\rangle$, $|12\rangle$, and $|03\rangle$. I find
\begin{align*}
Z &= \text{Tr} \, e^{-\beta (H-\mu N)} \\
&= \langle 30| e^{-\beta \sum_{\lambda=1,2} (E_\lambda - \mu) n_\lambda} | 30 \rangle +
\langle 21| e^{-\beta \sum_{\lambda=1,2} (E_\lambda - \mu) n_\lambda} | 21 \rangle + \cdots + \langle 03| e^{-\beta \sum_{\lambda=1,2} (E_\lambda - \mu) n_\lambda} | 03 \rangle \\
&= e^{-\beta [3 (E_1 - \mu)]} + e^{-\beta [2(E_1 - \mu)+(E_2-\mu)]} + e^{-\beta [(E_1 - \mu)+2(E_2-\mu)]} + e^{-\beta [3 (E_2 - \mu)].}
\end{align*}
On the other hand,
\begin{align*}
Z_1 &= \text{Tr} \, e^{-\beta (E_1-\mu)\hat{n}_1} \\
&= \langle 30| e^{-\beta (E_1-\mu)\hat{n}_1} | 30 \rangle +
\langle 21| e^{-\beta (E_1-\mu)\hat{n}_1} | 21 \rangle + \cdots + \langle 03| e^{-\beta (E_1-\mu)\hat{n}_1} | 03 \rangle \\
&= e^{-3 \beta (E_1 - \mu)} + e^{- 2 \beta (E_1 - \mu)} + e^{- \beta (E_1 - \mu)} + 1,
\end{align*}
and similarly $Z_2 = e^{-3 \beta (E_2 - \mu)} + e^{- 2 \beta (E_2 - \mu)} + e^{- \beta (E_2 - \mu)} + 1$. Evidently, $Z \neq Z_1 Z_2$, if my calculation is correct.

Where am I going wrong, and how can I understand Coleman's explanation in more concrete terms?

Comment: Is this in the context of "distinguishable" (classical) particles, or in the context of indistinguishable particles such as bosons?  If the latter, are any assumptions made about the density of the system and the average occupation number of each state?

Comment: This is a book on quantum many-body physics, in a chapter on quantum statistical mechanics. So I suppose that means these should be indistinguishable particles. The discussion is supposed to apply to both bosons and fermions, assumed to be in thermal equilibrium. I don't see any assumptions beyond this.

Comment: Is the notation nowhere explained in the book? Do you understand what tensor product (of vector/Hilbert spaces) are? Do you know what tensor products (or Kronecker products) of matrices/operators are?

Comment: Of course the notation is nowhere explained---it's a physics textbook. But yes, I do know what tensor products of Hilbert spaces and operators are, although I must be having some trouble implementing that knowledge for these spaces of indistinguishable particles. Perhaps the key is in understanding where I went wrong in my three-particle example.

Comment: You should use @username to notify another user in a comment. I will try to write an answer, when I have time. I think what Coleman wants to emphasize is that there is a natural isomorphism, roughly: $ F(H)\cong \otimes_\lambda F(H_\lambda)$, where $H=\oplus_\lambda H_\lambda$ and here $\lambda$ labels some single-particle states/basis (so $H_\lambda$ is one-dimensional) and $F$ denotes Fock space. This then allows to factorize the grand canonical (!) partition function.

Comment: Thanks @TobiasFünke for nudging me in the right direction. I believe I got it and wrote up an answer below.

Comment: On a general note: Please read [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) and consider to accept an answer. You can also accept your own answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to [TobiasFünke](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/795205/partition-function-for-independent-particles/795296#comment1785877_795205) and [LPZ](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/795288/389817) for suggestions here.

The example is incorrect because it works in the canonical ensemble, whereas Coleman is working in the grand canonical ensemble. So let us sketch a proof of the result, which is that $Z = \prod_\lambda Z_\lambda$.

Let $|n_1 n_2 \cdots\rangle$ denote a basis state in the occupation number basis corresponding to the given single-particle states.
Since
$$\langle n_1 n_2 \cdots | \sum_\lambda (E_\lambda - \mu) \hat{n}_\lambda |n_1 n_2 \cdots\rangle = \sum_\lambda n_\lambda (E_\lambda - \mu)$$
we have
\begin{align*}
\langle n_1 n_2 \cdots | e^{-\beta(H-\mu N)} |n_1 n_2 \cdots\rangle &= \langle n_1 n_2 \cdots | e^{-\beta \sum_\lambda (E_\lambda - \mu) \hat{n}_\lambda} |n_1 n_2 \cdots\rangle \\
&= e^{-\beta \sum_\lambda n_\lambda (E_\lambda - \mu)}\\
&= \prod_\lambda e^{-\beta n_\lambda (E_\lambda - \mu)} \\
&= \langle n_1 n_2 \cdots | \prod_{\lambda \, \otimes} e^{-\beta (E_\lambda - \mu)\hat{n}_\lambda}  |n_1 n_2 \cdots\rangle,
\end{align*}
where the last equality follows from the definition of a tensor product of operators. (Note that there is a mild abuse of notation here: we have been using $| n_1 n_2 \cdots \rangle$ to refer to an element of the many-body Fock space, but this last equality uses the fact that this is a tensor product state over the Fock spaces corresponding to each single-particle state $\lambda$. There is, in fact, an isomorphism between the many-body Fock space and the tensor product of the Fock spaces corresponding to each single-particle state, as discussed [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/738067/can-fock-space-be-written-as-a-tensor-product-cohen-tannoudji-vol-3-book) (intuitively, specifying an element in either space simply amounts to specifying the number of particles occupying the $\lambda$th single-particle state), so the equality can be justified.)
Summing both sides over all many-particle basis states $|n_1 n_2 \cdots\rangle$ yields
$$Z = \text{Tr} \, e^{-\beta(H-\mu N)} = \text{Tr} \, \prod_{\lambda \, \otimes} e^{-\beta (E_\lambda - \mu)\hat{n}_\lambda}.$$

The trace of a tensor product of operators is equal to the product of their traces. This can be shown by working in a basis (trace is basis-independent), in which the tensor product of operators becomes a Kronecker product of matrices, and computing the trace explicitly (for example, see [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tensor_product#Tensor_product_of_linear_maps) for the definition of the matrix Kronecker product in the $2 \times 2$ case). We therefore have
$$Z = \prod_\lambda \text{Tr} \, e^{-\beta (E_\lambda - \mu)\hat{n}_\lambda}. = \prod_\lambda Z_\lambda$$
as was desired.

Comment: Your answer goes in the right direction, but there is a problem: You have used $|n_1,n_2,\ldots\rangle$ to denote both a vector on the Fock space as well as a tensor product state; so this is an abuse of notation. See for example [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/738067/can-fock-space-be-written-as-a-tensor-product-cohen-tannoudji-vol-3-book). As I said, there is a canonical isomorphism...Apart from this, everything seems correct (of course, if everything is mathematical rigorous is another question).

Comment: @TobiasFünke Ah, so am I correct in saying, supposing that I use $|n_1 n_2 \cdots \rangle$ to denote an element of the Fock space, that the only problematic step is the equality $\langle n_1 n_2 \cdots | \prod_{\lambda \, \otimes} e^{-\beta (E_\lambda - \mu)\hat{n}_\lambda}  |n_1 n_2 \cdots\rangle = \prod_\lambda e^{-\beta n_\lambda (E_\lambda - \mu)}$? And for this, you'd like me to use the isomorphism you pointed out to map an element of the Fock space to a tensor product state, in which the action of the operator is as I wrote?

Comment: Yes, indeed. So it should read $\langle n|\exp \ldots|n\rangle=\langle \tilde n|\prod_{\otimes \lambda} \exp \ldots |\tilde n\rangle$, where $|\tilde n\rangle$ is the tensor product state corresponding to the Fock state $|n\rangle$. From that, it should follows that $Z=\mathrm{Tr}_F \exp \ldots =\mathrm{Tr}_\otimes \prod_{\otimes \lambda} \exp\ldots = \prod_\lambda Z_\lambda$. I hope the notation is clear.

Comment: @TobiasFünke Got it, thanks. Since this is an isomorphism, I think the abuse of notation is not too bad (if it's good enough for Coleman, it's good enough for me). However, I will edit my answer to make note of this subtlety. Thanks for all the help.

Comment: IMHO: I think if you see something for the first time, it should be stated as clear as possible. But sure, if you are fine with it, all is good.

Answer (score 3):

The method is not applicable in your example. The issue is that you are thinking in the canonical ensemble with fixed number of particles. Colman rather works in the grand canonical ensemble with fixed chemical potential that you then tune to match the expected number of particles. It is only in the latter that the independence can be used. You also need to be careful as you are implicitly assuming that the particles are bosons, Coleman's approach is more general and works for both.

I'll detail how the situations differ in the case of two orbitals of energies $E_1,E_2$.

The grand canonical approach (Coleman's) gives:
$$
Z = Z_1Z_2
$$
with:
$$
Z_i = \text{Tr}[e^{-\beta(E_i-\mu)n_i}]
$$
For bosons, this becomes:
$$
Z_i = \frac{1}{1-e^{-\beta(E_i-\mu)}}
$$
while for fermions:
$$
Z_i = 1+e^{-\beta(E_i-\mu)}
$$
If you think in terms of fixed expected number of particles, you'll need to solve for the chemical potential:
$$
N = \sum N_i
$$
with:
$$
N_i = \frac{1}{Z_i}\text{Tr}[n_ie^{-\beta(E_i-\mu)n_i}]
$$
which for bosons is:
$$
N_i = \frac{1}{e^{\beta(E_i-\mu)}-1}
$$
and for fermions:
$$
N_i = \frac{1}{e^{\beta(E_i-\mu)}+1}
$$
In the case of two orbitals, you can explicitly solve this by using the quadratic formula.

The canonical approach (your approach) needs to be distinguished between bosons and fermions. For bosons:
$$
\begin{align}
Z &= \sum_{N_1=0}^N e^{-\beta[E_1N_1+E_2(N-N_1)]} \\
&= \frac{e^{-\beta E_2 (N+1)}-e^{-\beta E_1(N+1)}}{e^{-\beta E_2}-e^{-\beta E_1}}
\end{align}
$$
which does not have an obvious factorisation, and is certainly not factored into independent factors.

In the case of fermions, it's faster to just enumerate the possible partition functions:
$$
\begin{align}
N &= 0 & Z &= 1 \\
N &= 1 & Z &= e^{-\beta E_1}+e^{-\beta E_2} \\
N &= 2 & Z &= e^{-\beta (E_1+E_2)}
\end{align}
$$

The two approaches agree in the thermodynamic limit, but for three particles in the boson case will not give the same results.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the very helpful response, clarifying that I should be working in the grand canonical ensemble. However, although you have stated that $Z = \prod_\lambda Z_\lambda$ only in the grand canonical ensemble, you have not given a proof of this for the grand canonical ensemble, which is an important point in the original question.